# Android :Display a dialog to enable wifi

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-wifi

I would like ,if the wifi is disabled , to display a dialog to the user ,that can decide if he wants to enable or disable the wifi.

Well i can see if the wifi is enabled or not, but how could i display that settings dialog.

This is the code i'm using :

```
if(wifiMan.isWifiEnabled()==false){
    Log.i("DEBUG","turning on wifi");
    wifiMan.setWifiEnabled(true);//I would like that the user decide
    }

  else {  
  Log.i("DEBUG","wifi is on");
   }
```

**PS** : i used : startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)); but i'm getting this error : ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS cannot be resolved or is not a field

I would like to have this interactive dialogue :

[image]

Comment: did you set permission  in manifest     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: yes i did , i can enable the wifi , but i would like that user decide to enable or not.

Comment: did you import, import android.provider.Settings;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try this way if that is not working. The problem is may be you import wrong namespace.
try this

> android.app.activity.startActivity(new
>   android.content.Intent.Intent(android.provider.settings.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SE‌​TTINGS));

In case above does not work.you can also try with this

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

Create dialog like this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Wifi Settings");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you want to enable WIFI ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        //enable wifi
                        wifiMan.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        //disable wifi
                        wifiMan.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: The second method is working , but it leads me to the settings wifi menu. what i need is to display an interactive message like in the edit.

Comment: why dont you show a simple alert dialog and add yes no button there and on yes click enable the wifi programmatically else disable that.

Comment: yes this, what i would like to do :D my question was how to display a dialog .

Comment: Thank you it works ,but still a little problem. When click on back button ,this alert disappears .How can i procede ,if i click on back button i exit completly from the application ?

Comment: back button has high precedence.unfortunately it will close the dialog. you need different logic to handle that.you need to override onBackPressed() method.

Comment: yes this what i need ,if i click on back button i exit from the app and the dialog is dismissed. I know that finish() close the app.

Comment: yes. so now change your logic according to your need.so you get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

Comment: This method is working , but it leads me to the settings wifi menu. what i need is to display an interactive message like in the edit.

Comment: Ok, but you didn't mention that you needed an **interactive message**, so I suggested this method. Anyway, if your problem is solved then well and good. Cheers!